# no data is available for encoding 1252

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, user-controls, propertygrid

i have strange problem where didnt expect.

I have custom dll with usercontrol (for WinForms), built with .NET4 VS2010 in Windows 7.

This usercontrol has a public property of class System.Text.Encoding.

I wrote own TypeConverter for it, to be available to choose encoding from property grid at design-time.

And got problem under Win8 (Win7 - no error).

At Win8 i have default encoding Western Europe (1252). So when i try to build simplest winforms app (only form and my usercontrol from my dll on it)

i receive build error message like in the header for Form1.resx:

Invalid Resx file. Type in the data at line 135, position 5, cannot be loaded because it threw the following exception during construction: No data is available for encoding 1252.

Doesnt matter if i chose another encoding before build, i again received same message.

Even when i removed 1252 from the list, changed to UTF8 whenever Encoding class used i still receive same message.

What workaround you can propose ? I want that property to be public, dont want to remove it, and want chosen encoding to be saved is resx or in any way.

At Win7 i didnt have such problem and didnt expect to have it at Win8.

Thanks